# Pull string on fluorescent light broke

Tags: electrical, switch, fluorescent

The pull string on my fluorescent light snapped off. Below is the image of the fluorescent light fixture and the cord used to come out of round section on the side. Does anyone know if this can be repaired easily? I am hoping to reattach the chain to the inside so it can still be functional. Because the cord snapped while the light was still turned on I can simply unplug/plug in the unit in order to get light so I hesitate to take the light fixture down to take a closer look unless someone thinks that it is fixable. I am just wondering the best approach here so any thoughts would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Cord snapped, or chain snapped? Was it a cord all the way in, or a cord that attached to a beaded chain, as is more typical of this sort of switch?

Comment: You won't know if it's fixable until you take it down.  Worst case scenario is you would have to replace the switch and there isn't a replacement switch available.  Best case scenario, you just need to replace the chain.

Comment: "Was it a cord all the way in, or a cord that attached to a beaded chain, as is more typical of this sort of switch?" It is a beaded chain and it snapped all the way in. Thank you for the notes

Comment: Looks like the lighting fixture was installed before the plumbing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get inside one of those fittings in seconds to check if the switch is still viable & merely needs the pull-cord reattaching.

Rotate the two tubes 90° to remove - the pins need to line up with the slots, reverse to re-insert. Underneath will be two plastic 'screw-heads', which also need to be rotated 90° to unlock the case cover. [A few you just lever out but most have the locking screws].

That will give you access to the entire innards. You can do this without even unmounting it [you'd have to do it to unmount it anyway, as that's where it will be fastened to the ceiling], so long as that pipe can be worked around.

*Note for future searches who may not have the exact same situation with a plugged appliance…* switch off at the mains first. Unplug or kill the circuit back at the box before opening. Use a mains tester, even a cheap one that beeps will give more false positives than false negatives.

Comment: I know it might be obvious, but you should also make sure to shut off the power, at the wall switch if there is one, preferably at the breaker, before making any such repairs.

Comment: OP already said it has its own plug, light is still switched on internally.

Answer (score 10):

Those switches are about $6 at your [big box](https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=chain%20switch) hardware or [online](https://amzn.to/3qxYOGa) store. Get one with wire leads instead of terminals.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very easy repair if you have done ANY wiring.  If not, watch some Youtube videos on properly installing wire nuts, and take clear  "Before" photos!!!

Comment: ... and most importantly: Don't forget to turn off the fuse for that light fixture before touching it! And use a tester to double-check that neither the wires, nor anything they touch, are "hot".